# Alfresco Community edition 5.1.x, how can I enable tooltips for text-field

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using alfresco community edition5.1.x I have create workflow using kick-start in workflow form I need enable tooltips for some text-fields.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the path `/opt/alfresco-community/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/xxx-config-custom.xml`

```
<field set="info" label-id="field:name" help="Tooltip text"/>
```

Tooltip text will display with the icon when you click the icon able to display the tooltip text, it should help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<field id="field:name" description="Tooltip text"/>
```

You can try *description-id* to map to an i18n string.

Comment: Thanks,I found the solution